# how to loop and generate hash key for every word in file

Tags: java, md5

May i know how do i loop so i can generate hash code for all the words in the file (.txt) ?
i'm already able to generate single hash code for the file.

the given loop reads and gets out the words in the text document.
but i'm unable to loop the hashkey generation in.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException { 

  JFileChooser chooser=new  JFileChooser();
  int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
  if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
  }
  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile());
  DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);    
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din)); 

  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
  MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

  String currentLine;
  byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

  int len = 0;
  while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(currentLine);
    md.update(buf, 0, len);
    System.out.println(currentLine);
  }
  br.close();

  byte[] bytes = md.digest();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);
  for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4));
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0x0F)));
  }
  String hex = sb.toString();

  System.out.println (buf);
  System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: You can convert a `byte[]` into hex with `String.format("%"+bytes.length*2+"x", new BigInteger(1, bytes))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generate a list of all the *lines* in the file which you then never seem to use. Maybe you should generate a list of all the *words* in the file by splitting each line on whitespace;

```
for (String word : currentLine.split("\\s+")) {
  list.add(word);
}
```

Then you can use this list to create a list of hashes for each word;

```
List<byte[]> hashes = new ArrayList<byte[]>(list.size());
for (String word : list) {
  md.reset();
  hashes.add(md.digest(word));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On high follow below steps.

1. Read line by line.
2. Once you get line `split` it on `\\s+`(space).
3. Now you have all words in array and then iterate it .
4. For each string (word) call `word.hashCode()`

Comment: Do you mean `\\s+` whitespaces as `\t` is a tab

Answer (score 1):

try using a tokenizer like this :

```java
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader("yourFilePath.txt"));
tokenizer.eolIsSignificant(false);
int token = tokenizer.nextToken();
while (token != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    if (token == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
        System.err.println(tokenizer.sval.hashCode()); // here use any hash method you like
    }
    token = tokenizer.nextToken();
}
```